# Pixel shifts from its actual position in Matlab geospatial plots?

Tags: matlab, matlab-mapping-toolbox

I am plotting a spatial map in MATLAB, where I have LAT-LON info for corresponding fill values.

Though the grid lines follows the meridian and parallels drawn in MATLAB plot domain, the fill values are shifting from their bounding grids.

[image]

How to resolve this error?

This is what I am trying

```
data_plot=reshape(data,10,9);
lat=reshape(lat,10,9);
lon=reshape(lon,10,9);

axesm('MapProjection','mercator',...
    'MapLatLimit', [19.5,24],...
    'MapLonLimit', [80,85],...
    'AngleUnits', 'degrees',...
    'MLineLocation',0.5,'MLabelParallel','south',...
    'PLineLocation',0.5,'PLabelMeridian','west',...
    'MeridianLabel','on',...
    'ParallelLabel','on',...
    'FontSize', 8,...
    'Grid', 'on',...
    'GLineWidth', 0.15,...
    'Frame', 'on',...
    'FLineWidth', 0.2,...
    'FFaceColor', [0.9 0.9 0.9]);

geoshow(lat,lon,data_plot, 'DisplayType', 'texture'); % save object
colormap(brewermap([],'Spectral')); % Use brewermap library for colorbar

set(gca,'Visible','off')
```

Here is the data that I have used

```
NaN NaN NaN -4.78691420806289   -8.13521846710988   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN -4.01605709290759   -4.20353507871522   2.33018806801104    4.70696490072666    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 0.774032705329402   5.02873177371123    6.06611111837680    -6.80420583641221   0.129609117788619   -4.82581469699584   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 4.36273713714724    -14.4196657518270   -2.17378348594956   -4.82319067390342   0.230288349807860   -22.3415772436864   NaN -8.67367866887345   NaN NaN 11.8370179262118    -3.33102817144554   7.74874986483622    -4.96601973372339   -5.08881416341006   -22.3485380432381   -20.7233696005194   -21.2373041517067   -21.0172684853155   NaN NaN -5.67344105387283   -5.92177293477175   -21.9347580147159   -24.5750303283218   -22.7917948590944   -16.7080123595719   -1.99235566573191   -20.0905129407017   NaN NaN -8.85439123876000   -14.4905474587236   -27.6201651860304   -28.0702972436629   -28.0926016470127   -28.4630871886205   -8.58431228057696   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN -24.5909372120401   -24.6228299340343   -31.3011311107455   -34.0008880519193   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN -30.9368757705375   -7.35439117585085   NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

[Link to Sample data](https://1drv.ms/x/s!ApBpIOvEejQlgr8fFhTE2OtuKQN92Q)

Comment: What values are in `lat` and `lon`? I suspect the problem might be related to `data_plot` being size 10x9 while the limits and spacing defined in `axesm(...)` result in a grid size 11x10. But I can't say for sure without `lat` and `lon`

Comment: @LeanderMoesinger axesm(...) gives the extent of lat-lon for map, it has nothing to do with data being plotted. I have updated the link to sample data in the question.

Comment: True, my bad. Very interesting question! If you don't find an answer here, you might want to consider moving it to stackoverflow (this question fits well on either site)